# Postgresql - optimal hardware for working with 50 milliion record retrival

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, hardware

I run postgresql 9.6 on aws rds with r4.xlarge. initially the table had less records and query was lightning fast later the table grew to 8 GB with 50 million records and query were extremely slow.

What's the optimal config needed for working with such data retrieval.

Server specs 
Cores 4 ram 30 gb

Comment: First of all, that's *NOT* a lot of data. Your server's RAM alone could hold the entire database in memory 3 times over. If you have performance issues you should check indexes and execution plans, not assume the hardware is insufficient. You should also check query patterns. If client applications open transactions and keep locks for a long time without reason, they'll end up blocking each other

Comment: In any case, you should first determine why performance is bad. You can't fix concurrency issues by throwing extra hardware for example. Adding missing indexes can improve performance 100x times or more *and* reduce blocking. A good schema can result in similar improvements. Or, to put it another way, you may find that you can use a far smaller machine for the same workload and still provide far better performance

Comment: Thanks for reply panagiotis. But my cpu reaches 80+% that's why I'm suspecting hardware can be pumped up will solve this issue

Comment: I'm jus running count * from the table which is very slow when we compare r4.xlarge and r4.large

Comment: The issue is with talend jobs which were holding the sessions and blocking cpu

Comment: In this case you'd have to improve the ETL script to block less. Eg load only modified records instead of everything. Directly copy changes to a staging/reporting instead of using multi-table queries to transform the data at the source.  Once you find a way to load only changed records run the ETL script every few minutes so you only load/lock a few records each time.